# Difference between Distributed File System, Cluster File System and Parallel File System

Tags: distributed-systems, parallel-computing, clustering, filesystems

On the internet, I am unable to find concrete definitions of these three types of file-systems. Can someone clearly explain the difference between these?

Comment: I'm generally a bit skeptical about questions asking for the difference between X, Y, and Z.  If you understand the topics X, Y, and Z, usually you should be able to identify their similarities and differences on your own.  It might be better to study each of those topics on your own, then do your own analysis of the differences... and if in the process of doing that, you discover some specific question about one of these topics, then ask about that.

Comment: Also, it's easy to write such a question and takes a bunch of work to do a careful analysis and write a good answer.  It's better if you do as much of that as you can before asking, and show your work in your post.

Comment: They sound like marketing terms for different variations of the same idea.